# mw_instance = middleware(adapted_handler) TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: django

I have upgraded python and django version.
resolved all the conflicts but unable to get the cause of this error.

old -> python 3.5, django 1.8
upgraded -> python 3.9 django 3.2
Any Idea why this error is for?

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 888, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/Users/m.susmita/code/venv3_9_0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/m.susmita/code/venv3_9_0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 138, in inner_run
handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
File "/Users/m.susmita/code/venv3_9_0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
File "/Users/m.susmita/code/venv3_9_0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 65, in get_handler
return get_internal_wsgi_application()
File "/Users/m.susmita/code/venv3_9_0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 45, in get_internal_wsgi_application
return import_string(app_path)
File "/Users/m.susmita/code/venv3_9_0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
module = import_module(module_path)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import
File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "", line 790, in exec_module
File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/Users/m.susmita/code/seldon-hercules/sp-hercules/opdashboard/wsgi.py", line 29, in 
application = get_wsgi_application()
File "/Users/m.susmita/code/venv3_9_0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
return WSGIHandler()
File "/Users/m.susmita/code/venv3_9_0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 127, in **init**
self.load_middleware()
File "/Users/m.susmita/code/venv3_9_0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 58, in load_middleware
mw_instance = middleware(adapted_handler)
TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
settings.py
# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    #     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

MIDDLEWARE = (
    'log_request_id.middleware.RequestIDMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'op_common.request_context.RequestContextMiddleware',
    # 'cas.middleware.CASMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: Show your `MIDDLEWARE` setting in `settings.py`

Comment: Added details of settings.py

Comment: You seem to have 2 custom middlewares? `log_request_id.middleware.RequestIDMiddleware` and `op_common.request_context.RequestContextMiddleware`? Can you show their code? Note that middlewares work a little differently from Django 1.10 onwards then they did before that, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-middleware

Comment: Thanks abdul for your quick suggestion, but that should not be an issue. If i remove one of them still getting the same error.

Comment: "Remove one of them" well the issue is not that they are two the issue is that they are likely old styled middleware, try removing both and you will see that at least _this_ error will go away (some other may come up)

Comment: Ahhh.... its working now, thanks for your suggestion. Thanks a lot :)!!!