# Django server not starting

Tags: django, django-settings

I am unable to start the server, it's giving me the error below, i am using only one model and migrations seems to be fine, any clue where i am going wrong in this

```
File "C:\Users\atifs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "C:\Users\atifs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\pythonmate_website\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\pythonmate_website\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 138, in inner_run
        handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\pythonmate_website\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
        handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\pythonmate_website\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 65, in get_handler
        return get_internal_wsgi_application()
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\pythonmate_website\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 45, in get_internal_wsgi_application
        return import_string(app_path)
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\pythonmate_website\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
        module = import_module(module_path)
      File "C:\Users\atifs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\pythonmate_website\pythonmate\mysite\wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
        application = get_wsgi_application()
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\pythonmate_website\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
        return WSGIHandler()
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\pythonmate_website\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 127, in __init__
        self.load_middleware()
      File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\pythonmate_website\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 58, in load_middleware
        mw_instance = middleware(adapted_handler)
    TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is caused by a middleware. Post the relevant part(s) of your `settings.py`.

Comment: Seems exactly like this question [mw_instance = middleware(adapted_handler) TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67859524/mw-instance-middlewareadapted-handler-typeerror-init-takes-1-position) - likely old styled middleware?

Answer (score 0):

As @jarad pointed out my middleware seemed to be using *white noise* middleware which is not required anymore after its update

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]
```